# Populate model properties inside of the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constructor, model, viewmodel, populate

I'm developing a webpage in MVC 5 and have been developing in MVC quite sometime now.

I always try/want to learn new ways/best practice of my programming skills. Right now I just stumbled upon something with ViewModels.

For example, I'm using the same ViewModel for multiple pages where I have Dictionary properties to fill my drop down lists.

So normally what I have done is creating a private method in the controller like "SetupViewModel" and then populate the dictionary to the model properties there and inside the model constructor just a "failsafe" creating an empty dictionary.

But for this project I'm working on now I thought that I would try to directly in the model constructor call my service method that returns the list for the ddl and then populate it right there.

Is there any advantages or disadvantages doing this way. What would you say is best practice? Because I can see some problems like, if the database goes down I could still load the page with empty values if I have the "setupViewModel"- method in the controller and with some try/catch or something preventing crash and if it is in the VM it would crash directly if I don't add some fail-safe in the services like returning empty lists if I can't get anything from the DB.

So it's equally much development but at different locations (well I can always have some fail-safe in the service ofc).

But the main question is, what is the best practice, populate model properties from model or controller?

Answer (score 0):

Personally in MVC I see accessing the data layer as a model concern. Controllers are supposed to do as little as possible.  So ideally I would in the constructor first initialise the dictionary to an empty one, then in a try..catch (which does nothing on error) get the database value for the dictionary and set it again.

Comment: But the model gets so "messy" with a lot of try/catch. I could return an empty list from the service method if the db connection breaks. But this is probably just personal how the code looks. It does the same thing :P